# Error for 'new' and 'edit' forms for has_many associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm a Rails newbie and am having a problem that I can't wrap my head around.

I have created 2 models with a :belongs_to/:has_many relationship.

```
class Inning < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :match
end

class Match < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :innings
end
```

I am able to get the parent (match) model working correctly and am also able to link the child (inning) model successfully.
My issue is that I am getting an error that I can't understand or resolve whenever I try to open the New or Edit form.

```
undefined method `inning_path' for #<#<Class:0x5751888>:0x54d3c08>
```

The routes are set up as follows:

```
  resources :matches do
    resources :innings
  end
```

Can anyone offer any suggestions on how to resolve this?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

Form code:

```
<%= form_for [@match, @inning] do |f| %>
    <%= f.error_notification %>
    <%= f.input(:inning_no) %>
    <%= f.input(:batting_team) %>
    <%= f.input(:bowling_team) %>
    <%= f.input(:score) %>
    <%= f.button(:submit) %>
<% end %>
```

rake routes:

```
           Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                   Controller#Action
    match_innings GET    /matches/:match_id/innings(.:format)          innings#index
                  POST   /matches/:match_id/innings(.:format)          innings#create
 new_match_inning GET    /matches/:match_id/innings/new(.:format)      innings#new
edit_match_inning GET    /matches/:match_id/innings/:id/edit(.:format) innings#edit
     match_inning GET    /matches/:match_id/innings/:id(.:format)      innings#show
                  PATCH  /matches/:match_id/innings/:id(.:format)      innings#update
                  PUT    /matches/:match_id/innings/:id(.:format)      innings#update
                  DELETE /matches/:match_id/innings/:id(.:format)      innings#destroy
          matches GET    /matches(.:format)                            matches#index
                  POST   /matches(.:format)                            matches#create
        new_match GET    /matches/new(.:format)                        matches#new
       edit_match GET    /matches/:id/edit(.:format)                   matches#edit
            match GET    /matches/:id(.:format)                        matches#show
                  PATCH  /matches/:id(.:format)                        matches#update
                  PUT    /matches/:id(.:format)                        matches#update
                  DELETE /matches/:id(.:format)                        matches#destroy
```

innings_controller.rb:

```
class InningsController < ApplicationController


  before_action :set_match, only: [:index, :new, :create]
  before_action :set_inning, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    #@innings = Inning.find(params[:match_id])
    @innings = @match.innings
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @inning = @match.innings.new  
  end
  def create
    @inning = @match.innings.new(inning_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @inning.save
        format.html { redirect_to @inning, notice: 'Inning was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @inning }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @inning.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @inning.update(inning_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @inning, notice: 'Inning was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @inning.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @inning.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to match_innings_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    def set_inning
      @inning = Inning.find_by_id(params[:id])
    end
    def set_match
      if params[:match_id]
        @match = Match.find_by_id(params[:match_id])
      end
    end
    def inning_params
      params.require(:inning).permit(:inning_no, :batting_team, :bowling_team, :score, :match_id)
    end

end
```

Comment: Your `set_match` should run for all your methods in your controller, remove the `only` stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would be great to view your "view" but I'm guessing the issue is that you are trying it:

`form_for @inning` instead of `form_for [@match, @inning]`

Also in your inning controller you should have something like:

```
before_action :set_match

protected
def set_match
  @match = Match.find(params[:match_id])
end
```

Comment: Also please put your innings_controller.rb code, I'm going to update my answer trying to put the code I think is missing in your controller

Answer (score 1):

Since you have nested your innings resource under matches, your names routes will also be nested with matches.

for new inning, named route will be

```
new_match_inning_path
```

your routes will be something like

```
GET     /matches/:match_id/innings(.:format)    innings#index   match_innings
POST    /matches/:match_id/innings(.:format)    innings#create  match_innings
GET     /matches/:match_id/innings/new(.:format)    innings#new new_match_inning

and etc
```

you can read the documentation for nested resources [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources)

Comment: I have used the correct path for the link based on the nested routes.  Thanks anyway.